# How to find what a specific TLD is?

Tags: tld

I am looking for a way to find out what is the ccTLD for a country.

I have a way to check if a TLD or ccTLD is real, but that sourced public info is a list, not a reference to what country they are connected to, or a description.

For example I was looking for ccTLD for Estonia. I already know `.es` is Espaneol (Spain). But it turns out that `.et` is Ethiopia. Luckily the above mentioned check can do a *starts with* , which gives me a list:

```
$ find-tld.sh e
EC
EE
EG
ER
ES
ET
EU
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a list somewhere on the internet that is ccTLD connected to country, or you could make that list yourself (but there are a *lot* of them - essentially you could use the example below to help create that list).

In the meantime, if you have a reduced set of verified ccTLD's that you want check against (like the list in the OP) then this will work:

```
TLD=au curl -r 0-1024 -s https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.$TLD | \
grep -m1 "<b>\.$TLD</b>" | \
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' | sed 's/\&\#91\;.\&\#93\;//g'
```

I adapted the above into a script, so that it does not ouptut a lot of (CSS) garbage when you lookup an invalid ccTLD.

You might be able to pull "for *country*" from the results, but thats quite complex when you check the results for `.ac` against the results from above list (some of which are ultra simple).

---

#### Explanation:

`TLD=` sets the valid Top Level Domain or Country Code you want information on, the results of which are taken from Wikipedia.

`-r 0-1024` only collects the 1st 1Kbyte of HTML via `curl`, as the 1st `grep` value (line) when "TLD is a false entry" is always over this value (1063 to be precise), while "TLD is a true entry" is always between 600 and 850 bytes, and will only return the line **bold** with the TLD name we are looking for, after which `grep` stops processing input (`-m 1`).

From the that 1st line returned by `grep`, the 1st `sed` strips out HTML tags, while the 2nd `sed` removes the HTML entities used to create citation
references on the Wikipedia web site, eg. `[2]`

The result is a paragraph of human readable text related to the Top Level Domain you are looking up. This is a reference, as opposed to computer readable text which could easily extract the actual country being referenced.